# Finding the basis for a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$ for x vector using equations

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm asking this to see if my answer is correct. 
let $S$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$ made up of the vectors

$x = [x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5]^T$

using the equations

$(x_1)+6(x_3)-2(x_4)-3(x_5)=0$

$(x_2)+3(x_3)+(x_4)+2(x_5)=0$

find a basis for $S$

in my answer i got the solution for $x_1$ and $x_2$

$(x_1)=-6(x_3)+2(x_4)+3(x_5)$

$(x_2)=-3(x_3)-(x_4)-2(x_5)$

$$
[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5]^T = x_3[-6,-3,1,0,0]^T,  x_4[2,-1,0,1,0]^T,  x_5[3,-2,0,0,1]^T
$$
Basis of $S = [-6,-3,1,0,0]^T,[2,-1,0,1,0]^T,[3,-2,0,0,1]^T$

Are these three vectors correct for the basis of the subspace?

Comment: Your result i s correct. Only it is not clear what does it means the line 
$$
[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5] = x3[-6,-3,1,0,0], x4[2,-1,0,1,0], x5[3,-2,0,0,1]
$$

Comment: thanks for confirming that! it's the notation my teacher requires. for example if you take x3 and multiply it across the vector [-6,-3,1,0,0] then it is the same as [-6(x3),-3(x3),(x3),0,0]. the vector contains values attached to the corresponding X value